# Date format doesn't validate at hosting server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

by using this script

```
  <script> 
        $(function () {
            $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
                 Globalize.culture("en-AU");
                if ($.browser.webkit) {
                    var d = new Date();
                    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
                }
                else {
                    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
                }
            };
        })
        $.noConflict();

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            $('#ReferenceDate').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                autoClose: true
            });
            $('#TransactionDate').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                autoClose: true
            });

        });
        jQuery.validator.methods["date"] = function (value, element) { return true; }

    </script>
```

in model class using annotation like

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime ReferenceDate { get; set; }
```

This function is well working in local IIS  server. but i am hosting in azure websites it give the error like as

> '26-08-2015' is not valid date for ReferenceDate

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue and noticed its to do with UK date format ie any day over 12 is failing hence it thinking its MM/DD/YYYY